# issue putting date value from server request in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular js to show data from a server.  It works fine but the issue is that the date value does not show due to input type "date" when i change the input type to "text" it works.  Below is my code:

html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <input type="date" ng-model="x.sdate">
</body>
```

js code

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http,$filter) {
    var param = getParameterByName('id');
    $http.get("http://socialdeal4u.com/demo/survey/api-delete.php?id="+param)
       .success(function (response) { $scope.x = response; });
</script>
```

Please tell what am i missing

Comment: [`<input type="date">`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D) needs an actual `Date` as a model. What does your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, the model for `<input type="date">` **must** be a `Date` object.

You need to transform the data from your API from a string to a `Date`. For example

```
$http.get('http://socialdeal4u.com/demo/survey/api-delete.php', {
    params: {id: param},
}).then(function(response) {
    $scope.x = response.data;
    $scope.x.sdate = new Date($scope.x.sdate);
});
```

This of course assumes that the `sdate` string in your API response is ISO 8601 compliant or otherwise usable in the `Date` constructor.